# Why do my variables disappear after using feature selection with step()?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I made a Multinomial Logistic Regression model using library(nnet) in R.
I notice I, one, get an error, and two, after using the step() function, my predictor variables convert into the variable I'm attempting to predict, solely (Depression).

`summary(multinom_model)$call`

produces:

```
multinom(formula = out ~ ., data = train)
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(vc)) : NaNs produced
```

BUT

`mult_model <- step(multinom_model, trace = FALSE)`

`summary(mult_model)$call`

*this* code produces:

```
multinom(formula = out ~ Depressed, data = train)
```

**Why is this happening? Also, both models predict the same output on the test data. Does it have to do with the warning message? How do I fix that?**

Comment: The details section of [`?step`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/stats/html/step.html) starts by saying that *"step uses `add1` and `drop1` repeatedly"*. The returned model has only the final variables, in your case only one. As for the other question, do you have constant variables, with zero standard errors?